# Map string on array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I have a class

```
class Data {
  static $array = [
    'k1' => [
      'k2' => 'val1',
    ],
    'a1' => [
      'a2' => [
        'a3' => 'val2',
      ]
    ],
  ];

  public static function getValue(string $key) {
    $keys = explode('|', $key);
  
    $array = self::$array;
    $lastKey = end($keys);
    foreach($keys as $key) {
      if (!isset($array[$key])) {
          return '';
      }
      if (is_array($array[$key])) {
         $array = $array[$key];
      } elseif($key == $lastKey) {
         return $array[$key];
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now I want that

`Data::getValue('k1|k2')` will return **val1**

`Data::getValue('a1|a2|a3')` will return **val2**

and so on

If there is no key it will return empty string

Is there a better way for it ?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
class Data
{
    public static $array =
        [
            'k1' => [
                'k2' => 'val1',
            ],
            'a1' => [
                'a2' => [
                'a3' => 'val2',
                ]
            ],
        ];

    public static function getValue(string $pipe_path) {
        $array = self::$array;
        foreach(explode('|', $pipe_path) as $idx) {
            if(!isset($array[$idx])) {
                return '';
            }
            $array = $array[$idx];
        }

        return $array;
    }
}
var_dump(Data::getValue('k1|k2'));
var_dump(Data::getValue('a1|a2|a3'));
var_dump(Data::getValue('foo1|bar2'));
```

Output:

```
string(4) "val1"
string(4) "val2"
string(0) ""
```

Comment: @Progrock updated the answer, thanks for pointing out the scope I was testing it in a plain file